# What is this mean <aaa> in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Below is my code

```
public static postData(language: string, money: number): Promise<testModel.Item[]> {
    return ........
    });
}
```

What is this code mean and Promise< testModel.Item[] > mean in here?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Promise<testModel.item[]>` is the function return type in this snippet. Eg, it declares that the function `postData` returns a promise that resolves with an array of `testModel.item`.

The `<>` syntax (in this case) is used to supply the parameters of a generic type. You can read about generics in typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Because TypeScript is statically typing, then sometime you want a function, or class that can accept a customizable Type.

For Example:

```
class Stack<TItem> {
    push(item: TItem) {/...}
    pop() -> TItem {... }
}

then you can use Stack<string>, Stack<number>....
```

In your application, applied to a `Promise<TResult>` where `TResult` is the expected type of the result of the promise.